# How can I find the first id within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create script that needs the id from this form. I want to find the first id within the otf_itm class. So in this case I am looking for town_id to be returned. I have tried a few different selections but so far they all have come back undefined

```
$('.otf_itm:first-child').attr('id');
$('.otf_itm').find('id');
$('.otf_itm').find().attr('id');
```

```
<div class="otf_itm">
    {if $towns|@count gt 0}
    <select class="form-control chosen add_town" name="town_id" id="town_id" data-rule-required="true" data-placeholder="Choose a town">
        <option value=""></option>
        {foreach $towns as $town}
        <option value="{$town.id}" {if $town.id eq $form_data.town_id}selected="selected"{/if}>{$town.town_name}{if $town.region_name}, {$town.region_name}{/if}</option>
        {/foreach}
        <option value="ADD_NEW">Add new town...</option>
    </select>
    {else}
    <p class="mt5">You have no towns configured.</p>
    <p class="mt5"><a href="#modal-1" role="button" id="town_id" class="showhouse-text" data-toggle="modal">Add new town</a></p>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: What's this stuff `{if $towns|@count gt 0}`?

Comment: What happens if `$towns|count` = 0?  The first child element won't have an ID.

Comment: Thats Smarty Templating syntax. Basicaly if there is an array of towns show the select box else show the link

Comment: @Archer the 2nd p tag with the link then holds the id

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('.otf_itm [id]:first-child').attr("id")
```

Of course the above works when your templating language is correctly rendering it to a valid html output.

Comment: The first element isn't guaranteed to have an ID.

Comment: Not really, `[id]:first-child` will only select a `:first-child` element that *also has an `id` property*.

Comment: @DavidThomas, well, if I use `[id]:eq(0)` then?

Comment: It'd probably work, but at that point our answers essentially become the same.

Comment: @DavidThomas, does css selectors evaluate from right to left? I though mine would select any element with id and then would select the first-child

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
// selects elements with an id attribute within the .otf_itm element:
$('.otf_itm [id]')
// retrieves the first:
.first()
// gets the id property from that jQuery object:
.prop('id');
```

Or:

```
// selects elements with an id attribute within the .otf_itm element:
$('.otf_itm [id]')
// retrieves the first:
.eq(0)
// gets the id property from that jQuery object:
.prop('id');
```

References:

- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer. You're a high rep user. I just wanted to know why I've you written *I'd suggest*. Just wanted to learn why.

Comment: Having a high rep just means I've been here longer, or I have more time that I'm willing to waste/spend here on the site; it doesn't mean I'm any better at programming/scripting :) my use of the phrase "I'd suggest" is purely because that's all it is, *a suggestion*, it works but the OP isn't forced or mandated to "do as he's told," I really can only advise, or suggest. :)

Comment: ah! I thought you suggested this because it had some performance benefits kinda thing. ;)